# how to show a summary of a file list grouped by directory

Tags: git, perl

Suppose I have a list of files, and I want to summarize them by directory, to a certain depth.

For example, I want to see which directories a git commit changed, or a git diff affects.

The output of `git diff --name-only` or `git show --name-only` lists something like:

```
foo/1.txt
foo/2.txt
bar/3.txt
bar/4.txt
```

but a summary by directory would show:

```
foo/
bar/
```

Comment: Adding an git commit example and desired output would be nice.

Comment: @StefanBecker done.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the file list to perl, then extract the first N pieces of the filename. (This bit expects all the items to have at least this depth!)

Then print the extracted text if it's not already been seen.

For example:

```
git show --name-only SHA | perl -n -e 'my ($root) = m[^((\w+/){DEPTH})]; print $root . "\n" if !exists $seen{$root}   ; $seen{$root} = 1;'
```

where DEPTH is replaced with the depth of directories to consider.